# Use Listbox and checkbox like CheckBoxList from .NET in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, checkbox, listbox

Im sorry for asking this basic question, but im tired of searching everything and i cant find anything usefull.

I want to use one list box with one checkbox in the datatemplate like the CheckBoxList in .Net, the only thing i want to do is: have the list of checkboxes with the name on front of it, select one, and on one button click event check the items inside the listbox and retrieve the text of the selected checkboxes.

Im a .NET programmer, but this is starting to anoying me.

Here is the ListBox XAML code.

```
<ListBox Height="299" Name="lstbEquipas" Width="432">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Name="ckbEquipa" Content="{Binding Designacao}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

this is what i use to populate the listbox and it works exactly like the CheckListBox in aspnet, a list of checkboxes with text on the front.

```
GameManager.GameManagerSoapClient GM;
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GM = new GameManager.GameManagerSoapClient();

            GM.LerEquipasAsync();
            GM.LerEquipasCompleted += new EventHandler<GameManager.LerEquipasCompletedEventArgs>(GM_LerEquipasCompleted);

        }

        void GM_LerEquipasCompleted(object sender, GameManager.LerEquipasCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument data = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
            var equipas = from query in data.Descendants("Equipas")
                          select new Equipa
                          {
                              ID = (int)query.Element("ID"),
                              Designacao = (string)query.Element("Designacao"),
                          };

            lstbEquipas.ItemsSource = equipas;
        }
```

And this is the classe used above.

```
public class Equipa
{
int iD;
string designacao;

public int ID
{
    get { return iD; }
    set { iD = value; }
}
public string Designacao
{
    get { return designacao; }
    set { designacao = value; }
}
}
```

All i want to do is in the button click event, get the text of the first selected checkbox in the ListBox. So i can send it to the webservice and save it to the database.

```
private void btnRegistar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ListBoxItem Item in this.lstbEquipas.Items)
    {
        //i want to check the checkbox were
    }
    //GM.InserirNovoUtilizadorAsync(this.txtLoginUtilizador.Text, this.txtLoginPassword.Password, 1);
    //GM.InserirNovoUtilizadorCompleted += new EventHandler<GameManager.InserirNovoUtilizadorCompletedEventArgs>(GM_InserirNovoUtilizadorCompleted);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to store the data for `ItemsSource` in a property :

```
public ObservableCollection<Equipa> Equipas { get; set; }

void GM_LerEquipasCompleted(object sender, GameManager.LerEquipasCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument data = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
    var equipas = from query in data.Descendants("Equipas")
                  select new Equipa
                  {
                      ID = (int)query.Element("ID"),
                      Designacao = (string)query.Element("Designacao"),
                  };
    Equipas = new ObservableCollection<Equipa>(equipas);
    lstbEquipas.ItemsSource = Equipas;
}
```

Then you can get list of all checked items from above property using LINQ :

```
private void btnRegistar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get only checked items, and store it in variable
    var checkedItems = Equipas.Where(o => o.IsSelected);

    foreach (Equipa Item in checkedItems)
    {
        //here you can save current item to database
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i think i got your idea, i added the bool isChecked in the class Equipas (there wasnt there yet), but it doesnt work with your code, the array returns empty

Comment: var checkedItems = Equipas.Where(o => o.IsSelected); All the items go with isSelected = false, and if on click we check the original array instead of the listbox array, isSelected is always false.